# How to position TopComponent windows into output and bottom of explorer in NetBeans platform

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a netbeans platform app and my output window opens up in the editor position and I have to manually relocate it to the bottom area every time i re-install the program. Also I have another TopComponent that I want to have start in the bottom of the "explorer" area on the left which should be already predefined. Is there a way to do that?

FYI - I am running on Ubuntu 12.04, so not sure if this is why i'm seeing this behavior.

Any advise greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have time to answer in complete so I'll point you to a source. Watch part 3 of the NetBeans Top Ten API series. At around the 32 min mark you'll get an explanation and method for doing this http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-10-top-apis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have open TopComponent wizard, you can set "window position" or you can "redefine..." modes for TopComponents.

```
//yourMode for exaple Editor or new mode, that was redefined by you
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "yourMode", openAtStartup = false)
```